# Possible bug in as.POSIXct

Tags: r, time, posixct

I am working with time data, and I covert it to POSIXct class (read as strings). When I do this it work with all my data but no with one specific string. What I do is in essences:

```
Time1 <- '1900-04-01' # First Year then Month then Day
Time1_convert <- as.POSIXct( Time1, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I do this vectorized and all my data is well converted. But with the date 1920-05-01

```
Time1 <- '1920-05-01' 
Time1_convert <- as.POSIXct( Time1, format='%Y-%m-%d' )
```

This return NA. I have no idea why this happens. If I add to the as.POSIXct function tz = 'GMT'; the time is well convert for all values. What I do not understand is why this happen and why this happen with this specific value when I have tried with more than 1500 different times values.

I add an image of the output:
[image: Output in RStudio]

More code added:

```
for( m in c(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)){ 
   print(as.POSIXct(paste0('1920-',m,'-01'),format='%Y-%m-%d'))
}
```

and the output is:

```
[1] "1920-01-01 CMT"
[1] "1920-02-01 CMT"
[1] "1920-03-01 CMT"
[1] "1920-04-01 CMT"
[1] NA
[1] "1920-06-01 -04"
[1] "1920-07-01 -04"
[1] "1920-08-01 -04"
[1] "1920-09-01 -04"
[1] "1920-10-01 -04"
[1] "1920-11-01 -04"
[1] "1920-12-01 -04"
```

Output of sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_AR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_AR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct('1920-05-01', format='%Y-%m-%d' )` works just fine for me!

Comment: Works fine for me too. May be a locale issue.

Comment: make sure it actually `1920-05-01`, there might be leading or trailing spaces

Comment: Trailing/leading spaces are taken care of by R in as.POSIXct()/as.POSIXlt()/as.Date()

Comment: Shot in the dark, make sure no zeros are accidentally O's?

Comment: same here... cannot reproduce based on the given data. voted to close.

Comment: A side note: why do you use `as.POSIXct` when you don't have times? Why not `as.Date`? Regarding the NA, my first thought was DST in the current tz. But: (1) "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC", and no one advances clocks at midnight do they? And (2) not in May?

Comment: I keep checking and the code looks fine but same NA value as output. With as.Date works fine but I need the time data to be  POSIXct class to further work and comparison. I add a picture of the output

Comment: Also confirming this is not reproducible; check that your characters are consistent in your date column. Maybe you have an "en" dash or an "em" dash separating the date parts?

Comment: If you typed in the commands in your console and go the results in the picture, you should seriously consider a fresh install of `R`. This is an odd one but `R` can be broken/corrupted so easily.

Comment: I add some code and its output to shown better the problem

Comment: Can you share the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I suspect Argentina had a time adjustment then. From here:  https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-336.10/zic.tproj/datfiles/southamerica      # From Paul Eggert (2002-01-22):
# <a href="http://www.spicasc.net/horvera.html">
# Hora de verano para la Republica Argentina (2000-10-01)
# </a> says that standard time in Argentina from 1894-10-31
# to 1920-05-01 was -4:16:48.25.  Go with this more-precise value
# over Shanks.

Comment: Yes, see more here: http://www.statoids.com/tar.html  That was a date when Argentina changed its time zone.

Comment: @JonSpring Perhaps post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local settings appear to be based in Argentina. As it happens, Argentina reset their time zone on that date from UTC-4:16:48 to UTC-4. I think this means that there *wasn't* a midnight in Argentina on May 5, 1920. When you convert that string to POSIXct, it interprets it at midnight that day in your local time zone, which by coincidence is a time that did not exist in Argentina. (This explains why it was not reproducible for others who tried the same code.)

http://www.statoids.com/tar.html

> Locations in Argentina observed Local Mean Time until 1894-10-31 00:00
>   (as measured after the transition). At that moment, the entire country
>   synchronized on Córdoba's Local Mean Time, which was UTC-4:16:48. The
>   next transition occurred at 1920-05-01 00:00, when clocks were set
>   ahead sixteen minutes and forty-eight seconds to be an even UTC-4.
>   Argentina remained unified on UTC-4 until its first daylight saving
>   time was inaugurated in 1931.

If you need a POSIXct object, you might consider:

a) specifying a different time zone where midnight existed on that day.

```
as.POSIXct("1920-05-01", tz = "UTC") 
# Or perhaps other nearby time zones didn't have that specific problem?
```

b) Storing the time in components, including one for date, and one for time within the day. e.g. `time = hour(Time1) + minute(Time1)/60`. It's a little unwieldy but it might be possible to perform the date / time calcs you need.